# Nginx Laravel Ubuntu Server Composer Update Changed permissions/Not staying

Tags: laravel, nginx, permissions, ubuntu-server

I have a Ubuntu server running nginx and laravel.  I recently had to run a composer update –no-dev and composer-autodump –o.  Now I’m getting the error message below when I login.

file_put_contents(/var/www/laravel/storage/framework/cache/data/45/0d/450dd23cd0918654a4bed8a88426d460115cac32): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I reran the command below

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/framework/cache/*
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/*
```

and I’m still getting the error on initial login.  I reload the page after several attempts and it takes me to where I’m trying to go.  Does anyone know why this is?  Thank you for your help

Is there another command I need to run for the permissions... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer from the original guide used.

sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/cache

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
sudo vi /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

change:

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

to:

```
user = vagrant
group = vagrant
```

**Solution 2:**
modify Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant/",owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"
```

owner/group set to **www-data, not vagrant**